# Get loaded images from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, uiimage

In my app there's a `UIWebView`. The loaded webpage in it has some images, and I would like to use these images in somewhere else (e.g. display them in `UIImageView`)

So is it possible to get the loaded images directly from `UIWebView` without downloading them again? What I am doing now is get the URLs to the images from the html file and download them, but this is too time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out: the key is to extract the images from the `NSURLCache`. However, since iOS 8, it seems you need to set the default cache as the first thing in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` for this to work. For example:

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:[[NSURLCache alloc]
    initWithMemoryCapacity:32*1024*1024 diskCapacity:64*1024*1024 diskPath:...]
```

Then after your `UIWebView` has finished loading:

```
NSCachedURLResponse * response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]
    cachedResponseForRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://.../image.png"]]];
if (response.data)
{
    UIImage * nativeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:response.data];
    ....
}
```

If you don't already have it, you can get an array of images from the `UIWebView` with

```
NSArray * images = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"var imgs = []; for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) "
        "imgs.push(document.images[i].src); imgs.toString();"]
    componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```