# Get data of a loaded WKWebView view

Tags: swift, swift4, wkwebview

I have to get the data of a `WKWebView` after it finished loading.

The entry point is clear. It should be the delegate method:
`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {}`. This allows me to check for an specific url pattern, etc.

But I have no glue how to access the Data object of a WKWebView.

I need this functionality to share a loaded PDF file in an embedded instance of a WKWebView. The original request has to be untouched due to form parameters.

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: what do you mean by `Data object of a WKWebView` ? you can check pdf url by `webView.url`

Comment: @Jack. I mean the "content" of the web view - in this case the pdf file as Data. The url is not a direct pdf link. It links to a web page that renders the pdf via some Javascript form code and returns (by setting content-type of response to `application/pdf`. Also it is secured by some Auth mechanism so it is not easy to use a session task.

Thats why I wanted to "recycle" the web view's data.

I also tried the `URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: URLRequest(url: webView.url)).data`approach but this leads to an html error page that says "you have to enable JS"

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624106/get-loaded-images-from-uiwebview then you need to write some javascript code.

Comment: That seams very hacky. I miss my `UIWebView`. Thanks buddy!